# Flutter Stream Works Only Once Per App Startup

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a stream that works when I first run the app in my android emulator but then replaces it with an empty one before failing to return anything until the emulator is stopped and restarted. The only way for me to get it to output anything again is to close the emulator and restart it. I would be perfectly happy if instead of a stream the asynchronous function simply ran once and returned the proper contents whenever the widget it is a part of is rebuilt. Any help on fixing this issue is appreciated.

```
  Stream<List<Memo>> getFeed() async* {

    List<Stream<List<Memo>>> streams = [];

    List<String> friends = await Firestore.instance.collection("users")
    .document(userid)
    .collection("friends")
    .snapshots().map(_snapshotToStringList).first;

      for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        streams.add(Firestore.instance.collection("memos")
        .where("owner", isEqualTo: friends[i])
        .snapshots()
        .map(_snapshotToMemoList));
      }

    yield* StreamGroup.merge(streams);
  }
```

The stream is recieved with

```
    return StreamProvider<List<Memo>>.value(
      value: dbService( user: widget.user ).getFeed(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: TestList(),
      )
    );
```

Then in TestList is

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final memos = Provider.of<List<Memo>>(context);
    print(memos);
    return (memos == null || memos.length == 0) ? Text('no content') :
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: memos.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(memos[index].body);
          }
        );
  }
```

I am new to flutter/dart so please be assume little prior knowledge in your recommendations/explanations, or ideally, please correct the code I have above

Comment: After some tinkering with other unrelated parts of the app it looks like it randomly gives proper output but the vast majority of the time it returns an empty/null array.

Comment: Are you using `flutter_bloc`?

Comment: @SanjaySharma No I am not, not do I know what that is

Comment: Having played around even more it looks as though whenever it runs it makes 3 returns in quick succession before stopping. Nothing, the content I want then nothing again. The last empty return overrides the content of the previous so it is as though it never returned anything.

Comment: @SanjaySharma It comes as part of the package https://pub.dev/packages/async. I use it to combine the list of streams into a single stream and it looks as though it gets the job done.

Comment: If it is of any significance, the friends array has been kept size 2 for the duration of the tests.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the way the steam is handled by StreamBuilder or other widgets. Can you share the code of how you are handling the output of the stream?

Comment: Please try the answer also it generates one stream only so it should fix the  issue if you are handling for one output only and it's more efficient way

Comment: @SanjaySharma I have added the code where I handle the stream output

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to replace this

```dart
 for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        streams.add(Firestore.instance.collection("memos")
        .where("owner", isEqualTo: friends[i])
        .snapshots()
        .map(_snapshotToMemoList);
      }
```

with the following

```dart
yield Firestore.instance
        .collection('memos')
        .where('owner', whereIn: friends)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_snapshotToMemoList));
```

And you have issue with the line `final memos = Provider.of<List<Memo>>(context);` as it will take the data as `null` when the response is not fetched and the request is in pending state. Try to use `StreamBuilder` to handle this. Check [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-with-streams-6ed8d0a63bb8)

Comment: This returns a type of Stream<Stream<List<Memo>>> which causes an error as the expected return type is Stream<List<Memo>>.

Comment: It's not like that in question. You can change it as it can be handled by one stream only.

Comment: How would I go about changing it? I have tried indexing and .first and changing the expected return type to Stream<Stream<List<Memo>>>. None of these have worked

Comment: Additionally, I used the loop because the 'friends' list length can be very large and surpass the 10 length limit of a single .where statement

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are handling the steams?

Comment: I have added the stream output handling. Also, I'd like to thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: Thank you, I am researching how to do so. Will this change the issue of it not always fetching good data? Also on the point of the friends list being longer than 10 is my conclusion that the above code will not work correct?

Comment: I used the streambuilder but the Stream<Stream<List<Memo>>> error came up again

Comment: Please don't use stream of stream and use `whereIn` or  `arrayContainsAny` as you will end up making so many requests and it's not cost-efficient

Comment: Just return single stream how I wrote in the answer

Comment: The single stream answer that you shared returns Stream<Stream..>, I do not understand how

Comment: I do not see alternatives to using whereIn because I first get a list of friends a user has then find their posts by searching the posts collection in firestore for posts that have a matching userid. This is the most efficient solution I could come up with without duplicating data.

Comment: But you will be making so many requests for the data and it will be slow so when you use `whereIn` you make only one request. And the map should return single `Stream`. Can you update the code?

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you so much. I changed yield to yield* and now it works. For the whereIn issue, I need to find a way to filter a list of posts using a long list of friends and this is all I could think of. You have been such an amazing help already but I would like to ask: can you think of a better way to do the filtering?